# Get attribute names of MongoMapper Document

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

I have the following class:

```
class Stock
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :isin, String
end
```

How can I determine the key names of the `Stock` class at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`keys`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/v0.11.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb#L20) method:

```
Stock.keys
#=> ["name", "isin"]
```